# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first ror app.
I have main page: `home.html.erb`
I have form there.

```
  <%= form_for(@lead ,:html => {:class => 'check_form'}) do |f| %>

      <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: 'phone' %>
    <%= f.submit "Check car status", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Backstory: a customer(I call him Lead can input his phone number and check status of his car  which is being repaired now.)

Right now this view `home.html.erb`is served by `static_pages_controller`

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
  def about
  end
  def contact
  end
end
```

I have also `LeadsController`

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  #before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
        @leads = Lead.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    Lead.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "record deleted."
    redirect_to leads_url
  end

  def show
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end
  def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    if @lead.save
      #sign_in @lead
      flash[:success] = "Request successfully created!"
      redirect_to @lead
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
    if @lead.update_attributes(status: params[:status])
      flash[:success] = "Information updated"
      redirect_to leads_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end



  private

    def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :car_type,
      :car_year, :car_manufacturer, :car_model, :photo1, :photo2, :coords )
    end

    # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

What I want to do when user inputs his phone number to find lead in database with the same phone number and show repair status to user.
But it generates an error:
`First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` 
So I got that `form_for(@lead..` here @lead is empty. 
But what should I do to get rid of this error.?

Comment: Where is `@lead` initialized?

Comment: @Makoto I am not sure where it initialized. I added code for my leadController. Right now I don't initialize it I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

As your view(`home.html.erb`) is served by `static_pages#home`, you should initialize `@lead` in the `static_pages#home` action

```
def home
  @lead = Lead.new
end
```

Comment: second question: I know how to find my lead by phone like this 'Lead.find(params[:phone])' but where I can put my  code?Should I ask this in comments or add another question?

Comment: @user2950593 You should put that in `leads#create` action :)

Comment: @user2950593 Yes... :)

Comment: if I already have code there like this `@lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    if @lead.save
      #sign_in @lead
   flash[:success] = "Request successfully created!"
      redirect_to @lead
    else
      render 'new'
    end`..  Then How I will be able to understand when user clicks  register  and when he just wants to find his already registered car by his phone number? Will be checking  `:phone field` for nill be good idea?

Comment: @user2950593 Can't understand what you are saying. Try posting an another question and explain it clearly.

Comment: see it please) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999656/ror-find-record-in-db-and-show-it-to-user