# Ror find record in db and show it to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first ror app.
I have main page: `home.html.erb`
I have form there.

```
  <%= form_for(@lead ,:html => {:class => 'check_form'}) do |f| %>

      <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: 'phone' %>
    <%= f.submit "Check car status", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Backstory: a customer(I call him Lead can input his phone number and check status of his car  which is being repaired now.)

Right now this view `home.html.erb`is served by `static_pages_controller`

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
   @lead = Lead.new()
  end

  def help
  end
  def about
  end
  def contact
  end
end
```

I have also `LeadsController`

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
*some code*

  def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    if @lead.save
      #sign_in @lead
      flash[:success] = "Request successfully created!"
      redirect_to @lead
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

* some code
end
```

What I want to do when user inputs his phone number to find lead in database with the same phone number and show repair status to user.

So back to my problem:
I know how to find lead by phone like this `Lead.find(params[:id])`
But where to write this code? I need to find lead by phone and then print it to screen. How can I do this?

Comment: LeadController's `show` method should delegate the lookup to the ActiveRecord class where you can have a method (or better yet a scope) named 'find_by_phone_number.

Comment: Here the customer(ie. lead) is already created in the DB?

Comment: @Pavan yes it is already created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do when user inputs his phone number to find lead in
>   database with the same phone number and show repair status to user.

Currently your form serves the wrong purpose. This requires a form with `GET` request. I'll be doing it by declaring a custom `route` like below

```
get :check_lead_car_status, to: 'static_pages#check_lead_car_status', as: 'check_lead_car_status'
```

And in the `static_pages#check_lead_car_status`

```
def check_lead_car_status
  @lead = Lead.find_by(phone: params[:phone]
end
```

And modify the existing form like below

```
<%= form_tag check_lead_car_status_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :phone, placeholder: 'phone' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Check car status", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And a page `check_lead_car_status.html.erb` with the below code

```
The Status of the Car is: <%= @lead.status %>
```

Comment: This is unknown syntax for routes declaration for me I knew I just knew the one from the tutorial like `match '/leads',  to: 'leads#index',            via: 'get'`

Comment: and it is workking))))))) this is really amazing) Thanks again man!

Answer (score 0):

youre redirecting to `@lead` which means should be the show path in the lead controller. which means you need to put that logic in a method called `show` in your Lead controller

then in your view (`views/leads/show.html.erb`) you can access that variable

---

edit:

if all youre trying to do is query by a different parameter, then you should look into the [active record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object). specifically section 1.1.5

`Lead.find_by(phone: params[:phone])`

Comment: I already have `def show
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
  end`

Comment: can you inspect the value of that variable? your corresponding `show` view will have access to it

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Inspect value of @lead? like i can write puts @lead to console for example will it be good?

Comment: yes. you should have a view located in `views/leads/show.html.erb` and if you interpolate `@lead` in that view, it should also come up

Comment: Well if I go to http://0.0.0.0:3000/leads/1 it will give me a user with id 1. I don't get how to get user with a phone xxxx.

Comment: if thats all you want to do, then search by phone number instead of by id. `Lead.find_by(phone: params[:phone])`. see section 1.1.5 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object

Comment: See answer I  accepted, I guess  it explains my problems, I had the wrong form. But thank you too man))) I really love Ror community it is very very supportive !)